# Fastlane windows cannot installing

Tags: windows, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

How to install **fastlane** in **windows**? i installed rubygems , but i dont know how to install fastlane on windows. please tell me how to install fastlane in windows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*fastlane* currently only runs on macOS and doesn't support Windows.

Update 2020: See answer below on how to get fastlane running on Windows.

Comment: is Linux supported by fastlane?

Comment: is this still true to this day?

Comment: You can achieve it by installing Ruby on your Windows machine. See my answer.

Comment: Wrong! It works on windows! See solution underneeth!

Answer (score 47):

1. Install `ruby` on your windows machine.
2. Go to your command line and type `gem install fastlane -NV`.
3. You have fastlane on your windows machine ready.

Comment: Will it work for publishing android studio application?
Have you tried it?

Comment: @AryeeteySolomonAryeetey, I am researching about fastlane for windows and saw this post of yours. I am trying to make fastlane work on my windows device but I don't actually know where and how to start. All I see are tutorials for macOS. I don't completely understand them and I was wondering if it would be worth my time to try harder if I want to learn Fastlane for my windows device? In short are the "steps" the same when working with Windows than in Mac? Thanks!!

Comment: I've successfully used it on windows as well. I had to run fastlane commands from MINGW64 terminal, because it relies on unix commands such as cat.

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris If it works for you, please upvote :)

Comment: it gives the following error: ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)
        unknown encoding name - CP720
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Comment: To the author: This is the real solution! It works for me directly! Thanks you so much :)

Comment: I am getting the following error on windows ERROR:  Error installing fastlane:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.8/ext/unf_ext
C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20220218-15756-1a9ghh.rb extconf.rb
Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/unf_ext-0.0.8/mkmf.log

Answer (score 6):

As @AryeeteySolomonAryeetey states it is possible to run fastlane on Windows.

But we experienced a few more issue, before we were up and running:

- Needs a terminal in interactive mode
- `ridk` needs to be install - at least on some machines
- Some fastlane commands does not work on Windows - you will have do some workarounds.

I have written a blogpost about the [Automated Android deployment with Fastlane on Windows](https://blog.vertica.dk/2019/08/15/automated-android-deployment-with-fastlane-on-windows/) **including a powershell setup script to do all the needed setup to be running Fastlane on Windows!**

Comment: It is possible to use firabase app distribuition on windows?

Comment: @WellingtonYogui I have not tried that on the windows machine because we run that lane on our CI - but I think would work just as other fastlane actions works on windows.

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard that blogpost is not available

Comment: @JebaPrince I am investigating that - the website has been rewritten but the blog was supposed to still be there.

Answer (score -4):

You can install via nodejs

```
npm install fastlane
```

Comment: but does it work? According to official site it still only runs on macOS

Comment: I guess the initial question doesn't mention if they want to mean the fastlane tool for mobile apps, or the npm fastlane, which is not related to the mobile app tool